# How can I solve typescript error 'x' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors

I am getting error

```
Property 'duni' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
```

at the line below

```
  @ViewChild('bhondu') duni: ElementRef<HTMLTableDataCellElement>;
```

Making it optional using `?` breaks code at other place where I use `this.duni.nativeElement`  giving`Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)` . How can I solve this error **without changing any property in the config files**?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

```js
@ViewChild('bhondu') duni!: ElementRef<HTMLTableDataCellElement>;
```

Comment: An alternative would be `@ViewChild('bhondu') duni: ElementRef<HTMLTableDataCellElement> | undefined;` which, then requires optional chaining to use, i.e. `this.duni?.nativeElement`. Horses for courses, basically!